# ServletRequest get name of actual page

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-filters

I am using a `Filter` and the `doFilter`-Function. I would like to know which site is being requested. Some function giving me something like `/firstDirectoryInWebDirectory/lala.jsp` would be perfect.

What is the way to go here? Using the context will be the right way, but I can't find any good method :-(

Thanks

Comment: In what way is `/firstDirectoryInWebDirectory/lala.jsp` a site?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`request.getRequestURI()` should return the part of the URL after the domain.

From there, you can strip the `request.getContextPath()`

(You'd have to cast the `ServletRequest` to `HttpServletRequest` first)

Comment: perfect. I didn't think about casting. Casting always hurts my soul. But that ways it works. Quite ugly :-)

Comment: You will have to get used to casting in servlet filters. Btw, if the answer works for you, you can mark it as accepted (tick below the vote counter)

Comment: Still had to wait 4 min to tick it :-)

Answer (score 0):

When I just started learning Java EE, it was casual to mix-up **ServletRequest** and **HttpServletRequest** methods. As [Bozho](https://stackoverflow.com/users/203907/bozho) said, type casting is necessary to access required methods.

This code will log access *time* and *IP* when the servlet named *"Test"* will be requested:

```
if (((HttpServletRequest)request).getServletPath().equals("/Test")){
            String IP = request.getRemoteAddr();
            System.out.println("Test Servlet:: Logged IP "+ IP + ", Time :" + new Date().toString());
        }
filterChain.doFilter(request,response);
```

Basically, the **request** object is casted from a generic request into HTTP Request and only then the return String of **getServletPath()** can be compared to whatever you want ("/Test" or "/firstDirectoryInWebDirectory/lala.jsp" or "whatever.html").